# JavaScript object detection

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype-programming, object-detection

I am currently practicing javascript and I'm currently having trouble with object detection.  I want to create an object and detect whether it exists.  Below is some example code I am currently using.

The code sample below is how I am creating my object.

```
var obj = obj || {};
```

Should I be using this?

```
if (typeof obj !== "undefined") {
   // code
}
```

Or this?

```
if (obj !== null) {

}
```

Comment: 1. There is no `!===`. 2. You haven't explained what you **really** need. Depending on the **real** aim the solution can vary

Comment: Why not simply `var obj = {}` to create a new object?

Comment: well if you are setting the obj to {}, it can not be null or undefined.

Comment: my bad, I meant typeof obj !== "undefined" and typeof obj !== null.  What I'm asking is..which method is best to determine if an object exists.  I have read online that some methods will produce false results, and I'm having trouble finding the right one.  hopefully I explained myself better. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @GregHewgill - If you want to initialize `obj` when it does not have a value, but otherwise leave it unchanged, then `obj = obj || {}` is the right idiom.

Comment: obj = obj || {} is the same thing as if (typeof obj !== "undefined") ?

Comment: @JaPerk14 - Not exactly. It will also initialize `obj` if it is `null`, but `null !== undefined`.

Comment: obj = obj || {} esentially means if ( !obj ) obj = {}. That's pretty simplified but should hopefully help provide some clarity on that area :)

Comment: @TedHopp: sure, but putting `var` in front of that totally changes the meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value `undefined` means that the variable has not been assigned a value. The value `null` indicates that it has been assigned the value `null`. The `===` operator (and its negation, `!==`) prevent [type coercion](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html).

Which is right? It all depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Both `undefined` and `null` are "falsy" values, meaning that each one evaluates to `false` in a boolean context (as do `false`, `0`, and the empty string).

Note that if `obj` is `null`, then `typeof obj` is *not* `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 0):

The usual practice is to use:

```
var obj = obj || {};
```

When that code runs, you can be certain that `obj` has been defined (because of the `var` declaration), though it may not have been assigned a value.

If the value of `obj` resolves to a "falsey" value, then you will assign a reference to a new object.

Possible outcomes are:

1. If `obj` has not been assigned a value, a new object reference is assigned.
2. If `obj` has previously been assigned a "falsey" value, it will be replaced by a new object reference (which may mess with whatever code assigned it the falsey value).
3. If `obj` has previously been assigned a "truethy" primitive value, the following assignments of properties to `obj` will throw an error and script execution will stop.
4. if `obj` is already a reference to an object other than `null`, then subsequent assignments of properties will be to that object. Depending on the type of object, things may be ok. Or not. Presumably something outside your control created the object and so may modify or destroy it without your knowledge. What will you do?

It is not possible in javascript to deal, in general, with cases 2 and 3, or 4 where it's not your `obj` you're dealiing with. So use a name that is unlikely to clash with any other and hope you get #1 or #4 and things go well.

Incidentally, code added after yours may still result (more or less) in #4, even if you had #1 at the point the code is executed.

There is no additional benefit to tests like:

```
if (typeof obj == 'undefined')
```

because the outcome is essentially the same.